# Adding an exception to kubernetes garbage collection

Tags: kubernetes, garbage-collection

In our project we have multiple cron-job using very large images, configured to run pretty often.

Whenever the garbage collection threshold is met images associated with those cron-jobs are removed, because they are not currently in use. Pulling those images from repository whenever they are needed introduces some problems due to their size.

My question is can i make it so that images associated with cron-jobs are ommited during garbage collection? A way to add an exception?

So far the only thing i came up with was creating another deployment that would use same image 24/7 with some changes so that it's execution doesn't finish normally. So that the image is in use when garbage collection is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I don`t know the way to specify a list of image name exceptions to Image Garbage Collection Policy, but maybe you can workaround it by overriding a default value (2 minutes) of 
`Minimum age for an unused image before it is garbage collected`.

through the following kubelet flags:

```
--minimum-image-ttl-duration=12h (by default it`s set to 2m - minutes)
```

the other user controlled flags are documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/#user-configuration)
The above one I found in kubelet [source code](https://github.com/sjenning/kubernetes/blob/0247a9acacd68f9eb55d6df2039f48351f2a0b6d/cmd/kubelet/app/options/options.go) on GitHub